# DecimalFormat not rounding to two decimal places correctly

Tags: java, double

In the program I am writing I have a percent change function. With the numbers I'm using, it is supposed to return .03, yet I just get 0. Using a calculator, the value not formatted would be 0.03303. I want the number to be truncated after the second decimal place, no rounding at all.

```
df = new DecimalFormat("###.##;-###.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

//later in code
return df.format(((price-base_price)/price)*100.00D);
```

Edit: all variable types are doubles. Base price is 756.60 and price is 756.85

Comment: Unless one or more of `price` and `base_price` is floating-point, you are donk integer division with an integer result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption about the value calculated in `((price-base_price)/price)*100.00D` is incorrect (I think you've probably invoked integer math, try `((price-base_price)/(double)price)*100.00D`). When I directly execute,

```
double value = 0.03303;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##;-###.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

I get the (requested) output

```
0.03
```

Comment: Casting to a double does not work. Is there some sort of problem with the math there?

Comment: Almost certainly. We can't tell, because we don't know the types (or the values) in `price` or `base_price`. However, `0.03303` will print as `0.03` above.

Comment: can u provide data type of variables and example value??

Comment: Perhaps the problem is where you're using it... how precisely are you using it?